# neo4j2.2 + jdk1.8 GraphDatabaseService.createNode() fail

Tags: java, neo4j

Here are the test code:

```
   GraphDatabaseService graphDS;
   for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        Transaction tx = graphDS.beginTx();
        try {
            Node graphNode = graphDS.createNode();
            System.out.println("graphNode.ID:" + graphNode.getId());
            graphNode.addLabel(label("person"));
            tx.success();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            tx.failure();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            tx.close();
        }
    }
```

It sometimes success, sometimes fail, when fail, there is no exceoptions, and it will also output nodeId, but there are no nodes created in database. If fail, it will all fail to create 50 nodes in one loop. 
It is very odd, hope somebody could show me why, thanks very much!

Comment: Some more context would be helpful? How do you check if the nodes have been created or not? How to you initialize your graph db instance? Do you close it using `shutdown()`?

Comment: I found out Transaction tx = graphDS.beginTx() may create different Transactions when creates TopLevelTransaction, it will success, when creates PlaceboTransaction,it will fail. How can I fix it?